# Facebook Graph API - Access token from code - Service temporarily unavailable

Tags: facebook-graph-api, facebook-access-token

I'm trying to fetch a user access token by code with the FB Graph API.

This is the API request that im sending:

```
https://graph.facebook.com/v17.0/oauth/access_token?client_id={APP_ID}&client_secret={APP_SECRET}&redirect_uri={REDIRECT_URI}&code={CODE}
```

I get the `{CODE}` by sending the user to: `https://www.facebook.com/v17.0/dialog/oauth`, from which i get the code no problem. The issue is that I keep getting this same response, no matter what.

```
"error" => [
    "message" => "(#2) Service temporarily unavailable",
    "type" => "OAuthException",
    "is_transient" => 1,
    "code" => 2,
    "fbtrace_id" => {SOME_CODE},
]
```

I tried waiting some time in between the API calls, but nothing changed.

Also tried changing the `redirect_uri` parameter (tried setting it the same as the `redirect_uri` sent with the `v17.0/dialog/oauth` URL), didn't help.

Also changed the APP mode from **Testing** to **Live**, didn't help.

Comment: Sending the absolute identical `redirect_uri` value in the second step is not optional, but actually a requirement.

Comment: I did also try that and i get the same error response. Does it have to be the same URI from which the initial request gets sent or does that not matter?

Comment: No, it just has to be the exact same value used in the login dialog call.

Comment: Nope, doesn't change a thing, still the same error

Comment: How are you making the request?

Comment: Locally through PHP with `curl`, setting the URL as i mentioned in the question with all the needed params

Comment: Please show the actual code (in the question, not as a comment), otherwise it's hard to tell if you might have made any mistakes.

Comment: Eh...PEBKAC...typo in request URL, all is good :) Thank you nontheless!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

PEBKAC, there was a typo in the request URL sent to the API.